# Tcl bug on Mavericks using tkinter and Python 3

Tags: macos, python-3.x, tkinter, tcl, activetcl

Using tkinter with Python 3 on a Mac running Mavericks I have come across the following bug ...

```
https://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/#apple-8-5-9
```

As recommended I have installed ActiveTcl, and ensured it is in my PATH variable.  However when I run tkinter code I still encounter the bug, which causes updates to the application to not appear until you physically interact with the interface by clicking with a mouse etc.

The symptoms include the text box not being updated as you type, and radio buttons requiring two clicks to update etc.

I have the preinstalled Python for Mac along with 3.3.5 and 3.4.1.  All have the same issue despite reboots and changing python versions.

Has anyone managed to work around this?

Answer (score 0):

Homebrew has just updated the Python3 install available to version 3.4.1.  So I removed all Python 3.x installations from my machine.

Then installed Active Tcl from : http://www.activestate.com/activetcl/downloads

then ran :

```
brew install python3
```

This newer version of python now picked up the newly installed ActiveTcl (the previous version did not for some reason) and the problem is now resolved.